# Keras Stateful LSTM get low accuracy when testing on training set

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, stateful

Generally, I use the stateful LSTM to make predictions. When I train the LSTM, the output accuracy is quite high. However, when I test the LSTM model on the **training set**, the accuracy is low! That really confused me, I thought they should be the same. Here are my codes and the outputs. Is there anyone knows why such things happen? Thank you!

```
model = Sequential()
adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.add(LSTM(512, batch_input_shape=(12, 1, 120), return_sequences=False, stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])

print 'Train...'
for epoch in range(30):
    mean_tr_acc = []
    mean_tr_loss = []
    current_data, current_label, origin_label, is_shuffled = train_iter.next()
    for i in range(current_data.shape[1]):
        if i%1000==0:
            print "current iter at {} with {} iteration".format(i, epoch)
        data_slice = current_data[:,i,:]
        # Data slice dim: [batch size = 12, time_step=1, feature_dim=120]
        data_slice = np.expand_dims(data_slice, axis=1)
        label_slice = current_label[:,i,:]
        one_hot_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(label_slice, num_classes=8)
        last_element = one_hot_labels[:,-1,:]
        tr_loss, tr_acc = model.train_on_batch(np.array(data_slice), np.array(last_element))
        mean_tr_acc.append(tr_acc)
        mean_tr_loss.append(tr_loss)
    model.reset_states()

    print 'accuracy training = {}'.format(np.mean(mean_tr_acc))
    print 'loss training = {}'.format(np.mean(mean_tr_loss))
    print '___________________________________'

    # At here, just evaluate the model on the training dataset
    mean_te_acc = []
    mean_te_loss = []
    for i in range(current_data.shape[1]):
        if i%1000==0:
            print "current val iter at {} with {} iteration".format(i, epoch)
        data_slice = current_data[:,i,:]
        data_slice = np.expand_dims(data_slice, axis=1)
        label_slice = current_label[:,i,:]
        one_hot_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(label_slice, num_classes=8)
        last_element = one_hot_labels[:,-1,:]
        te_loss, te_acc = model.test_on_batch(np.array(data_slice), np.array(last_element))
        mean_te_acc.append(te_acc)
        mean_te_loss.append(te_loss)
    model.reset_states()
```

Here is the program output:

```
current iter at 0 with 13 iteration
current iter at 1000 with 13 iteration
accuracy training = 0.991784930229
loss training = 0.0320105217397
___________________________________
Batch shuffled
current val iter at 0 with 13 iteration
current val iter at 1000 with 13 iteration
accuracy testing = 0.927557885647
loss testing = 0.230829760432
___________________________________
```

Comment: This is just overfitting (and its not related to programing).

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thank you for the comment. However, I actually test on the training set, not on the validation set...Do you still think this is an overfitting problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is the problem: it seems that in my code (stateful LSTM), the training error does not really imply the real training error. In other words, more iterations are needed before the model can work well on the validation set (before the model is really trained). Generally, this is a silly mistake:P